# How could killing themselves possibly help people get out of the loops?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-endless

In **The Endless** (2017), there are a number of people who got stuck in time loops and are trying to find a way to get out. Upon the loop reset they are killed by "It" and then they continue living in the following cycle.

Why do they choose to commit suicide before the reset? How could that possibly be a way out of the loop? If the person dies and the loop stops then the person would just remain dead. It is not looking for a way out, it's more like giving up. Is there any rationale in that?

Comment: I haven't seen this movie to get the gist of it's cause and effects, but it's possible that killing oneself could be some kind of variable that could push for potential change in another iteration, as casualty loops in sci-fi often push for some kind of variable that provides variation, as a means to examine what a constant and variable in any given universe or timeline may be...

Answer (score 3):

It's important to note that there are various areas with their own loops and their own loop duration--from a few seconds (the tent loop) to several years (the camp's loop). That's why some of those stuck in the loop are being driven crazy by it (like Carl) and some seem alright with it (like the camp residents).

As for why some characters commited suicide:

- **Carl**, apparently, has been playing with suicide for quite a while, saying, "you get used to it--suicide option." He realizes that he's probably stuck forever ("if you let it have you and you're still in the borders when the loop resets, you'll be stuck as shit forever"), but keeps committing suicide because he doesn't know how else to try to break it, I guess. It seems to be a form of escapism for him (he complains "it doesn't let me dream, it does it so my mind never leaves this place, these three hours") as well as a form of rebellion (he shoots at "the thing" and screams at it happily before he shoots himself).
- **Michael** sets his house on fire because, in Michael's words, "the one thing I do know for certain is I would rather reset things on my terms than let that fucker do it for me..." He also mentions "I keep thinking there's going to be this configuration that's going to break us out of the story...", so it seems like he hasn't given up and he keeps experimenting.

Comment: From what you propose there seems to be no solid logic in their actions. Escapism and rebellion are driven by emotions, not reason. If Michael succeeds and breaks out of the loop, what use in it for him, if he is already dead? These characters do not seem to make their best choices. The way I take it: no logic = plot hole. A lot of inconsistencies with Carl also: how can he coexist with his dead body and why do we see him walking at day time if his loop only has 3 hours? I mean, a curious film, but does not seem to be thoroughly thought through.

Comment: I agree that it's emotional rather than logical, though I don't think it's a plot hole. These characters are so frustrated with their fate and logic hasn't helped them before (if you watched Resolution, you'd know Michael attempted to appease "it" at first), so they're really just... doing whatever.

Comment: Both object permanence and daylight behave strangely in the movie. I'm not sure if there's some logic behind it or if it's just random. It's not just him running in the daylight, though--once day flickers to night, for example. Also for the main characters, daylight is consistent no matter the time loop, so perhaps daylight is independent of time loops. As for the dead body, I have no clue how that works--I didn't understand that part myself.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's pretty excruciating going through the time loop reset. Carl mentions this when Justin first meets him at his caravan. Carl seems to think it's better killing himself than be alive when time resets.