# Do the characters that are stuck in the loop actually remember their past loops?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-endless

Do the characters in The Endless that are stuck in the loop actually remember their past loops? It seems like yes, because they all have knowledge of the loops and are angry about it.

But that raises the question of why does the loop for them always start the same way? eg. The gun-nut tweaker and his friend always start the loop with the same greeting. If they remember the loop, wouldn't that change?

Same with the 5 second looper. Wouldn't he stop making the same jump out of his chair move after a hundred years of this?

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/91560/how-could-killing-themselves-possibly-help-people-get-out-of-the-loops